# can i put password for sql database like (test.mdf) to secure it if no what is he best way to secure my database

Tags: sql-server-2005

i devoleped windows application with c# and i use local sql database i want to secure it 
from admins -
can i put password for sql database like (test.mdf) to secure it   if no what is he best way to secure my database

(in other words)
can i keep my database not authenticated with windows and only be seen for auser i define

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's no 100% secure method to achieve what you want. You could protect Stored Procedure using WITH ENCRYPTION, but if somebody really wants to find out what your code does, he can find a way (e.g. with SQL Profiler).
If the issue is data sensitivity, you could encrypt the values before saving them in the database, but this will require you to modify your application and possibly add significant overhead. Also, unless you use some kind of obfuscation, your code can be reverse-engineered (actually, it can be even if you obfuscate it, it just takes longer).

In my experience, the most effective way to protect the data is via License Agreements. If customer tries to "play around" where he should not, then you have the rights to suspend support, charge extra fees to fix issues and, eventually, you have ground to sue them if you're afraid they "stole" your intellectual property.